# 100 percent width navbar has gap at top

Tags: css

This css below works with a workaround of taking the margin at -22px in the body.  I was wondering if there might be a better way to do this.  I have a full width background image and I want the nav bar to be the same.

```
html {


  background: repeating-linear-gradient(transparent 0%,transparent 90%,#000000 100% ),
              url("../../Images/bg2.jpg") center center no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 135%;

}
body{
    margin: -22px auto;
padding: 0 auto;
}
nav{

   width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    padding: 0;


    background-color: white;

}
```

Comment: Not enough code. Give us the HTML and any other CSS that you're applying.

Comment: Have you tried setting margin and padding to 0 in the html block?

Comment: The only HTML the OP has is a `<nav>`

Answer (score 0):

### CSS

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/KuagG/)

```
html {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/1800x900);
  background-size: cover;
}

body{
    margin: 0; /* override the default 10px margin */
}

nav{
   width: 100%;
   float: left;
   background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: The problem with the method you have is the image will be shrunk to match the height of the body height which makes the image scrunched down.  When I set the height to 135% in the html element it works but just keeps giving me the top margin above the nav bar.  Its a problem I cant figure otu